# How to copy old data and insert new renamed data back to same table by retaining other values

Tags: sql, database, oracle, cursor

I have item_Details table with 3 columns named as itemID, itemName, itemValue. I would like to copy itemName (i.e book) for all itemID with corresponding itemValue and rename book as textBook for few selected itemID's and insert back to table by retaining old itemValue for all corresponding itemID.

Attached image explains what i am look for, [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this sql query

```
update item_Details set itemName = "textBook" where itemName=="book"
```

Comment: what is the criteria for naming the itemName to "book" or "textBook"?

Comment: for all itemID's which belong to companyID=1 itemName has to be replaced to textBook. So i believe i got the answer :)  `update item_Details set itemName = "textBook" where itemName=="book" and (select item_id from company where companyID = 1)`

Answer (score 1):

As presented, this will do it:

```
UPDATE myTable SET itemName='textBook' 
WHERE itemName='book' 
AND itemID NOT IN (%itemsToKeepTheSame%);
```

Essentially, no reinsertion, you're just changing the data. Right?

Comment: well the problem is i have itemID's which has to retain itemName as book.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, then?

```
UPDATE item_Details 
SET itemName = "textBook"
WHERE itemName == "book" 
AND NOT itemId IN (108, 109);
```